# Applet AWTPermission

Tags: java, applet, awt

I made an applet which can be run if add the permission to java.policy(See below).

```
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "createRobot";
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "readDisplayPixels";
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard"; 
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessEventQueue"; 
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "showWindowWithoutWarningBanner";
```

Otherwise java console will show:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied("java.awt.AWTPermission" "createRobot")

How to do it with a product way since users dont want to modify the policy file?

In addition, the applet has already been signed and the files below are put in the server.

> ```
> ScreenShot.cer
> ScreenShot.store
> ScreenShot.jar
> ScreenShot.policy
> ```

HTML tag:

```
<applet name="SnapShot" archive="ScreenShot.jar" codebase="." code="ScreenShot.class" width="1" height="1" mayscript="true">
    <param name="cache_archive" value="ScreenShot.jar">
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true">
    <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
</applet>
```

Comment: *"I have already done the applet signature"*  Does that mean you digitally signed the applet? *"..and put the files below in the server."*  The only file of those 4 that needs to be on the server is the `myApplet.jar`.  The rest are redundant.  But just noticed the difference between `myApplet.jar` & `ScreenShot.jar`.  Don't paraphrase when describing these things.  Is it the first name, or the 2nd?

Comment: It is a mistake; actually, it should be ScreenShot.jar. I just corrected. Thanks for reminding

Comment: OK..  again, *Does that mean you digitally signed the applet?*

Comment: Yes, it does. But still suck with the AWTPermission

Comment: How big is the Jar? Can you upload it somewhere that I can download from (to check the digital signature)?

Comment: I create an repository in github:  https://github.com/max90727/ScreenShot

Comment: 1.7 Meg?!?  When I asked 'how big is the Jar?' I was hoping you'd take the hint to make a Jar of less that 5KB!  It would take less that 200 lines of code to test those 4 permissions..

Comment: alright, I though it could be clear. but the JAR file is around 23KB. You can download at http://temp-share.com/show/YgFbcdy0y

Comment: It shows a warning that might be meaningful.  Further details in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8387983/418556)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I want to enable copy/paste on my applet. I added grant all permissions to my.policy. And self-signed my applet. I still got Access denied. Can you help me show which step I do wrong? There is only granting more pivileged outside sandbox to trusted-sign applets, isn't there?

Comment: @KenBlock Copy/paste is a whole different (more complicated) situation.  You'd be best off asking a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question dulicates one from here where i've posted an answer:

[java.security.AccessControlException when using java.awt.Robot class for screen capture in applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381538/java-security-accesscontrolexception-when-using-java-awt-robot-class-for-screen)